# Nissan Sentra vvl

Tags: nissan, sentra, tuning

I'm driving sti 2 liter with vvl engine. I recently tuned my car. It has a dictator management.

Will disconnecting my battery affect the settings done with tuning?

Answer (score 1):

Usually these processing units in your case the dictator mangement system functions are programmed into a chip. So it just boots when the battery is on. So they cannot be erased until you reset them using a hardware programmable device which mostly the service centers have. They will mostly reset the dictator system but not be able to change how it works. This is just my understanding as vehicle CPU's work the same.